# Is the set of the exact decimal numbers such that their inverse is also an exact decimal number dense?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I have recently come up with a question which has become harder to prove or disprove than what I initially thought.

> Let us first denote by $\mathbb{E}$ the set consisting on all the
>   exact decimal numbers; namely, the numbers that can be written in base
>   10 using only a finite number of decimals. Then, the question is the
>   following one:
>
> Is the set
>
> \begin{equation} A=\left\{x \mid x\in\mathbb{E}\wedge
> \frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{E}\right\} \end{equation}
>
> dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

For now, all I have been able to do is to find an explicit characterization of the set $A$, for which it can be shown that can be written as

\begin{equation}
A=\left\{(-1)^k\cdot2^m\cdot 5^n\mid k\in\{0,1\}\wedge m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}.
\end{equation}

On the one hand, when trying to use basic real analysis theory to do a similar proof than the one used to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, one will be able to see that further difficulties appear when dealing with exponential expressions.

On the other hand, the previous difficulties made me think that the result might be false. Therefore I have tried to find a neighbourhood $\mathcal{E}(x)$ of a number $x$ not belonging to $A$, for instance $x=3$, such that $A\cap\mathcal{E}(x)=\emptyset$, but with no success either.

Comment: Aren't your exact decimal numbers just a subset of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @postmortes and as $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ that observation doesn't solve the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's dense. Taking logarithms, it's the same as saying that
$\ln 2$ and $\ln 5$ generate a dense subgroup of $\Bbb R$. But a non-dense
non-trivial subgroup of $\Bbb R$ must be the set of multiples of a fixed real. But $(\ln 5)/(\ln2)$ is irrational, which rules that out.

Comment: +1 - though you might need an extra minor step to cover negative decimals